# This link downloads a file : Mimecast CloudPagesURL

Tags: marketing-cloud, html, cloudpage

I have a custom Profile Centre and I'm using CloudPagesURL() to pass subscriber info and redirect to the centre. Some of the corporate subscribers who are using "Mimecast" are complaining about a warning when clicking an unsubscribe link within the email => "This link downloads a file".

What could be the problem on the Marketing Cloud side of things?

Comment: what are you looking for  can you explain clearly

Comment: Is the 'unsubscribe link' the same as the 'custom Profile Center' you are talking about? So that you are under the impression the error is caused by CloudPagesURL() function?

Comment: hard to say what the problem is, but if CloudPagesURL() is indeed the issue, a workaround is to use encryptSymmetric in the emails, and decryptSymmetric on your Cloudpage to pass encrypted parameters between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After conducting an investigation I believe this due to custom settings that were applied to the Mimecast software. Not related to Marketing Cloud functionalities.